# How to hover individual li rather than all of the content listen in ul?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a graphic design portfolio for myself, but my coding abilities are not the greatest. I'm trying to make a list with my projects and everything is working fine except for the hover function. The default state of the images is set to 60%, and I want individual images change to 100% when it's being hovered, but for some reason ALL OF THEM change when I hover on which ever one.

HTML CODE

```
<!-------PROJECTS----->
    <ul class="projects">
            <li><a id="myLink" onclick="on();return false;"><img src="images/gb_men.png" width= "100%"></a></li>
            <li><a id="myLink" onclick="on();return false;"><img src="images/juniors_full.png" width= "100%"></a></li>
            <li><a id="myLink" onclick="on();return false;"><img src="images/post_worlds_women.png" width= "100%"></a></li>
            <li><img src="images/Cheques.jpg" width= "100%"></li>
            <li><img src="images/WP_Banner.jpg" width= "100%"></li>
            <li><img src="images/GL_Banner.jpg" width= "100%"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS CODE

```
.projects {
    opacity: 60%;
    margin-left: 320px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 20px;
    position: static;
}
.projects:hover {
    opacity: 100%;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.projects > li {
    height: 540px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: static;
    content: "";
    list-style-type: none;
}

.projects li img {
    object-fit: cover;
        min-width: 300px;
        max-width: 480px;
        height:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: 1.: Opacity has to go to `.projects > li` and 2.: the whole hover need to be on `.projects > li:hover`. With your current styles, no matter which list element you are hovering, you are always hovering the project and therefore trigger the opacity for the the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding class to  element, you should add different classes to each and every

element. Suppose class of a

element is "class1" then do like this-

`.class1:hover { background-color: red; }`

Do like this for every class!

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `opacity: 60%` and hover effect to the **.projects** class which is the container of the images. So the hover effect is working for the whole container.

If you want to add a hover effect on the images individually you have to set the opacity to the class or tag (`.projects li img` in this case) that represents them.

```css
.projects {
    /*remove opacity from here*/
    margin-left: 320px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 20px;
    position: static;
}
.projects > li {
    height: 540px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: static;
    content: "";
    list-style-type: none;
}

.projects li img {
    opacity: 60%;  /* add opacity here*/
    object-fit: cover;
        min-width: 300px;
        max-width: 480px;
        height:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.projects li img:hover{ /*add hover effect for the images themself*/
  opacity: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="projects">
            <li><a id="myLink" onclick="on();return false;"><img src="images/gb_men.png" width= "100%"></a></li>
            <li><a id="myLink" onclick="on();return false;"><img src="images/juniors_full.png" width= "100%"></a></li>
            <li><a id="myLink" onclick="on();return false;"><img src="images/post_worlds_women.png" width= "100%"></a></li>
            <li><img src="images/Cheques.jpg" width= "100%"></li>
            <li><img src="images/WP_Banner.jpg" width= "100%"></li>
            <li><img src="images/GL_Banner.jpg" width= "100%"></li>
</ul>
```